# Route can not be found when page is refreshed in Vue 3 bundled by webpack 5

Tags: webpack, vuejs3, vue-router, webpack-dev-server

I have confronted a problem during using Vue 3 that bundled by webpack 5. In my project,   build tools  like Vue-cli is not used.

I defined vue-router and it only works when navigates, but when make page refresh, the following error appears on screen page:
`Cannot GET /home`

Here is my webpack config:

```js
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const { VuetifyPlugin } = require("webpack-plugin-vuetify");
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require("css-minimizer-webpack-plugin");
const htmlWebpack = require("html-webpack-plugin");
// const CacheLoader = require("cache-loader");
// const { SwcMinifyWebpackPlugin } = require("swc-minify-webpack-plugin");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin =
  require("webpack-bundle-analyzer").BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");

const ImageMinimizerPlugin = require("image-minimizer-webpack-plugin");

// Config
const config = {

  mode: "production",
  cache: true,
  performance: {
    maxEntrypointSize: 4000000,
    maxAssetSize: 2000000,
  },
  // Plugins
  plugins: [
    // new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
    }),

    new htmlWebpack({
      title: "Home page",
      template: "/src/index.html",
      filename: "index.html",
    }),

    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new VuetifyPlugin(),
    new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
    // new CacheLoader(),
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
  ],

  entry: {
    index: "./src/main.js",
  },

  // Ouput
  output: {
    filename: "[name].[chunkhash].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
  },


  // module
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "esbuild-loader",
        options: {
          loader: "tsx",
          target: "es2015",
        },

    
      },

      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: "vue-loader",
      },

      // Store css files in specific  separare file
      {
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },

      // Load and optimize images with different formats
      {
        test: /\.(jp?g|png|gif)$/,
        type: "asset/resource",

        generator: {
          publicPath: "assets/images/",
          outputPath: "assets/images/",
          filename: "[name][ext]",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
        type: "asset/resource",
        generator: {
          publicPath: "assets/fonts/",
          outputPath: "assets/fonts/",
          filename: "[name][ext]",
        },
      },
    ],
  },

  // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin(), new CssMinimizerPlugin()],
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: "vendors",
          chunks: "async",
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

module.exports = {
  ...config,

  cache: {
    type: "filesystem",
    cacheLocation: path.resolve(__dirname, ".test_cache"),
    compression: "gzip",
  },
};
```

And my routes is :

```js
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from "vue-router";
import Home from "../pages/Home.vue";
import About from "../pages/About.vue";
const routes = [
  { path: "/", component: Home },
  { path: "/home", component: Home },
  { path: "/about", component: About },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
});

export default router;`
```

Additionally, my main.js contains:

```js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import "./styles/button.scss";
import "./styles/main.scss";
import vuetify from "./plugins/vuetify/index.js";
import router from "./router/index";
import App from "./App.vue";

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(vuetify);
app.use(router);
app.mount("#app");
```

Also, packages and devDependencies are as follows:

```json
 {
  "name": "webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf build",
    "build": "npm run clean && webpack",
    "preview": " http-server build",
    "serve": "webpack serve"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.16.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.8",
    "@iconify/vue": "^4.1.1",
    "@mdi/font": "^7.2.96",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.26",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^10.2.4",
    "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "deepmerge": "^4.3.0",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^8.0.1",
    "esbuild-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "image-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^3.8.2",
    "imagemin": "^8.0.1",
    "imagemin-mozjpeg": "^10.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.2",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.3",
    "postcss-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^8.3.0",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^4.4.1",
    "sass": "~1.32",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.0",
    "sharp": "^0.32.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.1",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4",
    "vue-loader": "^17.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.13.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/vue": "^2.0.17",
    "@mdi/js": "^7.1.96",
    "axios": "^1.3.3",
    "chart.js": "^4.2.1",
    "esbuild": "0.17.15",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "http-server": "^14.1.1",
    "imagemin-gifsicle": "^7.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "svg-url-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue": "^3.2.26",
    "vue-chartjs": "^5.2.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.6",
    "vuetify": "^3.1.12",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.8.0",
    "webpack-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.1"
  }
}
```

How can solve this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by *"In my project none of build tool like Vue-cli is used."*? Could you post the contents of `package.json > devDependencies`?

Comment: @tao I meant that i didn't use vue-cli.

Comment: So are you using `vite` or have you written your own webpack based bundler for Vue? Because, afaik, there are only two available bundling options for Vue: `@vue/cli` (webpack based bundler) or `vite` (rollup based bundler). The fastest way to know what you're using would be to look into `package.json`'s `devDependencies`. Another way would be to run `yarn why rollup` and `yarn why webpack` in console (if you use `yarn`)

Comment: yes, I've written my own Webpack based blunder for Vue. And, also, the packages are provided in the post.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your router config (except you say *"And my **routes** is"*, when you probably mean *"And here is my **router**"*). Also I doubt it has anything to do with the fact you don't use `@vue/cli`, if everything else is working as expected. Would you be able to repro the issue in a *runnable* [mcve]? I recommend codesandbox's [import](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/getting-started/your-first-sandbox#import-local-projects-via-cli), but you can use any similar service, as long as it reproduces the bug.

Comment: The only slightly weird thing you're doing is using `Home` component twice, instead of using [alias](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html#alias). But I tried what you have in [this demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-vuex-4-vue-router-forked-pfq8m8?file=/src/router/index.js) and it seems to work, no problem. Note: using `alias` instead of having two separate paths serving the same component are not the same thing. In what you have, you can navigate between `/home` and `/` back and forth, because they're separate route entries. With `alias: '/home'` you can't.

Comment: I have two questions for you: a) does loading `/about` directly also fail? if it does, then adding `devServer: { historyApiFallback: true }` to your webpack config might help. First seen [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1254#issuecomment-351773724) on a very similar issue to yours.

Comment: @tao , I add devServe:{historyApiFallback:tue}. it works correctly. thanks.